Putting a discontinuity point inside Fourier series.
The problem seems to be simple.
What is the value of the function at x=4 of the Fourier series for the function defined as:
$2 $ if $ 0 \le x \le 2$
$4 $  if $ 2 \le x \le 4$
$-2 $ if $ 4 \le x \le 2\pi$
$f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$
I have found the Fourier series of the function, which is:
$f(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\left(5-\pi\right)+\frac{2}{\pi}\left(\left(\frac{3\sin\left(4n\right)}{n}-\frac{\sin\left(2n\right)}{n}\right)\cos nx+\left(\frac{2}{n}+\frac{\cos\left(2n\right)}{n}-\frac{3\cos\left(4n\right)}{n}\right)\sin nx\right)$
I know that the answer should be 1 because when putting a point of discontinuity into the Fourier series, the result should converge to the average of values that a discontnuity point can take, which in this case:
$\frac{1}{2}(4-2)=1$ for $x=4$
But how I can prove this?
I have simplified the series for the $x=4$ case:
$f(4)=\frac{2}{\pi n} \sin{2n} (4 \cos{2n}+1)+\frac{2}{\pi}(5-\pi)$
How should I move further?
